# Object sender as parameter for validating current textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to accomplish Winforms validation pattern for example check for empty string in textbox. So if I have textbox named `txtBox1` and event handler `txtBox1_Validated`. I wonder is it possible to use `object sender` as identifier for current textbox property?

For example I have working solution where I send `Text` property of the current textbox as an argument to `ValidateTextBox` method like this

```
private void txtBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(txtBox1.Text);
    ...
}
```

I'm wonder is it possible to use object sender in above method to to replace `txtBox1.Text` parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you've attached `txtBox1_Validated` to the appropriate control, absolutely:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;
bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(textBox.Text);
```

This means you can share the same method for several controls, of course.

EDIT: As the other two answers (at the time of writing) have used `as` instead of a cast, let me explain why I've very deliberately used a cast.

You'll be hooking up the event handlers yourself. You *know* that `sender` must be a `TextBox` - if it isn't, that indicates a bug in your code. With a cast, you'll find out about that bug. Using `as`, it will *silently* be ignored - and you'll quite possibly never fix the bug.

Comment: Just to expand upon this; it would allow you to write one single txtBox_Validated method that you can wire up to all your text boxes, so you don't have to write one for every text box.  That's probably the point of your post, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Jim: Yup, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can:

```
private void txtBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    if(txt != null)
    {
       bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(txt.Text);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually, *if(txt != null)* is [If Ok](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IfOk) anti pattern

This would be better:

```
private void txtBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    if(txt == null)
    {
        // Handler error
    }

    bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(txt.Text);
}
```

Comment: I definitely prefer using a cast here instead of `as` - if `sender` *doesn't* refer to a textbox, that's due to a bug, right? Why would want to keep going, oblivious to the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right. That's bug. But with *as*, you can safely handle it.

Comment: But you don't. You completely ignore it - you didn't even *mention* the possibility of detecting the problem in your answer. You could *log* it - but in my view, in the face of known broken code, an exception is a better option. It's much harder to ignore.

Comment: Please see my edit. Of course if you just ignore errors, it's better to use your version. But I think it's better to handle errors safely and always log it somewhere.

Comment: It's a *bug*. It's not an error like a file being present, or something like that. It's the same sort of bug as passing `null` to a method which requires a non-null argument - which would give an `ArgumentNullException` in idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the `sender` parameter to an instance of the correct object.

E.g.

```
private void txtBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myTextbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (myTextbox != null) 
    {
        bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(myTextbox.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to write something like

```
private void txtBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isEmpty = ValidateTextBox(((TexBox)sender).Text);
}
```

but why not use Validator controls instead?

Comment: `((TexBox)sender).Text` - otherwise, you would try to convert the string `sender.Text` to a `TextBox`.

Comment: @Chips_100 Thanks! That's what u get for typing on the phone :) corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Sender variable is the object that triggered the event. You need to cast the object to access their properties:

```
TextBox myObj = sender as TextBox;
if(myObj != null) 
{
 // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       if ((sender == (object)button1))
 }
```